# ¿Cómo evitar la superposición de divs jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Cómo puedo evitar que un div pueda pasar por encima de otro al hacer drop o sea que no traspase al otro div y respete la posición del otro.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(".draggable").draggable();
   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable" style="width:100px; background:blue; color:white">
 Primer div
</div><br>

<div class="draggable" style="width:100px; background:blue; color:white">
 Segudndo div
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452185/restrict-jquery-draggable-items-from-overlapping-colliding-with-sibling-elements

Comment: Muchas gracias! eso era justo lo que necesitaba :)